# Usage of silcrow (§) in French

Tags: anglais, syntaxe, typographie

As a native French speaker I usually associate the silcrow symbol `§` as a symbol that refers to a paragraph which seems to be its standard use in French:

https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paragraphe_(symbole)

However, in English, that symbol is not a paragraph, but a section sign:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Section_sign

That means it can be used to refer to another chapter:

> §2.2 (chapter 2 section 2)

In French, according to Wikipedia, it would be better to write this instead:

> chap.2, § 2

What is the correct use of the § sign and does it differ between these two languages?

Comment: La question ne porte-t-elle pas plutôt sur le sens du mot *section* en anglais ?  En typographie les deux mots ne recouvrent pas les mêmes notions dans les deux langues. En français on dit « Chapitre 2, paragraphe 2 » là où en anglais on dit « *Chapter 2, section 2* ».  § est appelé en français « symbole de paragraphe » et en anglais *section sign*. Tu peux aussi constater que le mot *section* de wikipedia en anglais n'a pas de renvoi à un article en français et que la page d'homonymie du mot « section » en français ne comporte pas de référence à un article sur la typographie.

Comment: @Laure Bonne remarque, le terme section en anglais est défini par `a distinct part or subdivision of anything`. Antidote définit un paragraphe de la même manière que `paragraph` en anglais. Donc *paragraph* == paragraphe et *section* == ???

Comment: Personnellement, j'utilise "§" pour référer à n'importe quelle partie numérotée d'un document. Donc s'il y a une partie "3.4.2.1", je vais le référencer en disant "§3.4.2.1 du document X", et à l'oral je dirait "paragraphe". Il y a en effet une différence avec la notion de paragraphe habituelle qui est délimité par des simples sauts de ligne...

Comment: Voir mon commentaire à la réponse ci-dessous. Je ne voulais pas faire de réponse parce que ce que je dis porte sur la langue anglaise et que ce ne serait pas au bon endroit. But just found the answer to what I think your question is on [ELU](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/264730/what-is-the-difference-between-a-pilcrow-sign-and-the-section-sign). And [this on writers](http://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/3644/when-should-one-use-a-section-sign).

Comment: § is called a [section sign](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Section_sign) in English. "Paragraph sign" in English refers to the pilcrow: (*pied-de-mouche*) in French ¶.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En complément sur le paragraphe en français : si un paragraphe est numéroté avec une séquence débutant par des chiffres alors on peut y référer avec le symbole [§](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=1873) (voir [exemples](http://www.orthotypographie.fr/volume-I/abreviations-01.html) de renvois sur *orthotypographie.fr*, ex. « voir : § 3.12 » et on a un paragraphe ainsi numéroté).

---

Dans *Le bon usage* (14<sup>e</sup>), par exemple, Grevisse et Goosse marquent chaque « article » ou paragraphe portant sur un sujet d'un nombre séquentiel à partir de 1, puis découpent ensuite avec des lettres ou des chiffres divers alinéas etc. Ils réfèrent dans le texte ainsi qu'à l'index à ces paragraphes, par ex. dans le texte : « voir : § 134, c ». Par ailleurs on nous explique qu'on parle aussi d'alinéa « à chaque passage après lequel on va à la ligne. Dans l'usage courant, on dit parfois *paragraphe*, mais il est préférable de garder ce nom pour les divisions marquées par une numérotation explicite. » ( § 118, b)

---

*Orthotypographie.fr* a une entrée pour [*paragraphe*](http://www.orthotypographie.fr/volume-II/pacte-point.html#Paragraphe) qui contient des informations sur l'abréviation formelle et le signe en question. Son emploi est limité : « Il doit être nécessairement suivi d’un nombre exprimé en chiffres ou d’une combinaison quelconque de signes indiquant son rang » et « le moindre déterminant exclut que l'on fasse appel à lui ». L'abréviation « régulière » est « paragr. » (aussi [ici](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=1808)). On ne double pas le signe au pluriel : § 8.1 et 9.43 ; § 4, 5, 8. Et on a l'espace insécable qui le suit. On retrouve essentiellement les mêmes informations (on dit du signe § qu'il « ne s'emploie que devant un chiffre ») dans le *Lexique des règles typographiques en usage à l'imprimerie nationale* (2002), où on donne l'exemple « § 5 et 6 ».

Comment: Orthotypographie  a aussi une entrée pour alinéa. Je pense qu'il n'y a pas de normes scientifiques et qu'elles peuvent être définies par les éditeurs. On peut aussi regarder avec intérêt les [normes de Légifrance sur la division d'un texte](https://www.legifrance.gouv.fr/Droit-francais/Guide-de-legistique/III.-Redaction-des-textes/3.2.-Organisation-du-texte/3.2.2.-Division-du-texte).

Comment: Merci ! [En effet](http://www.orthotypographie.fr/volume-I/accolade-allemand.html#Alinea). La normativité c'est surtout d'employer uniformément et de manière cohérente un code particulier, qu'on aurait choisi à l'édition effectivement. C'est un sujet difficile, que je connais peu, et je ne fais essentiellement que reproduire le contenu que j'ai trouvé.